# PowerBI Custom Visual - d3.Selection error

Tags: typescript, d3.js, powerbi

When coding a custom barchart for powerbi I get an error with a d3 typing. I had errors with other d3 typings when following the microsoft instructional video on youtube, but I have figured out that those errors were due to the d3 update to v4 and I was able to fix those errors. However I am running into one error with the d3-selection typings and I am unable to find a solution.

[image: Picture of Error in Visual Studio Code.]

I cannot find anyone who has the same error and to my best knowledge the update to d3 isn't what is causing it. The error message I am getting it:

> 'Generic type 'Selection' requires
>   4 type argument(s).'

If I add the other 3 arguments that are required I get other errors in my code and from all the searching that I have done it doesn't look like anyone else has any other arguments.

code that I have:

```
private svg: d3.Selection<SVGElement>;
```

with additional arguments (creates other errors):

```
private svg: d3.Selection<SVGElement, any, any, any>;
```

or:

```
private svg: d3.Selection<SVGElement, null, null, null>;
```

Does anyone know if there is any fix to this error? I am new to typescript and javascript and whereas I am starting to understand the logic, I can't seem to find anyone with the same error or a solution to the error anywhere. I could add the 3 extra arguments and go through and try and fix the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Rrt7.png) that will appear due to that, but it doesnt seem that anyone else who is creating these custom visuals has any additional arguments.

Answer (score 0):

For [d3 v3](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/5fb85c244c8f9215c1cdbfa71aafe2e5536a23da/types/d3/v3/index.d.ts), the interface for `Selection` is:

```
interface Selection<Datum>
```

While for [d3 v4](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/5fb85c244c8f9215c1cdbfa71aafe2e5536a23da/types/d3/index.d.ts), it is changed to:

```
interface Selection<GElement extends BaseType, Datum, PElement extends BaseType, PDatum>
```

Therefore, from your error message (requiring 4 arguments), it seems that you still have the wrong version (v4) of typings installed for d3.

If you [install](http://blog.jongallant.com/2016/11/pbiviz-12-d3-35-reference/) the correct version (v3) of typings then it shall work fine.

[image: result]

Comment: Hi @dashboard_m does this help solving the issue after all? If so, you can [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/313506) to positively close the question.